# Retrieve all users from wordpress database via REST/JSON API

Tags: users, plugin-json-api, rest-api

I've read that the WP REST API v2 retrieves only users that have made a post for the blog. I'm developing an iOS and Android app that needs to use the Wordpress registration.

How I could retrieve a list of all users registered to my Wordpress blog? Even those that never wrote a post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to stackoverflow user Milap !

You can get all users even they have not created any post, for that you need to modify rest-api plugin.

Open `wp-content/plugins/rest-api/lib/endpoints/class-wp-rest-users-controller.php` file, you will find below code on line number 106,

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'list_users' ) ) {
    $prepared_args['has_published_posts'] = true;
}
```

Change it to below,

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'list_users' ) ) {
    $prepared_args['has_published_posts'] = false;
}
```

If you don't want to modify plugin, put below code into current theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'rest_user_query' , 'custom_rest_user_query' );
function custom_rest_user_query( $prepared_args, $request = null ) {
  unset($prepared_args['has_published_posts']);
  return $prepared_args;
}
```

You are done.

FYI: i choose to edit the API file and it worked.