# Fetching all users that didn't post with rest api (current version 2)

Tags: rest-api, users

By default, wordpress only shows you the users who have posted on the site through the `/wp-json/wp/v2/users`

I want to fetch all users whether they have posted or not (using wordpress as a headless cms)

[Retrieve all users from wordpress database via REST/JSON API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218865/retrieve-all-users-from-wordpress-database-via-rest-json-api)

this link above explains it and it is very straight forward but it is implemented when the rest api was a plugin before it became a core part of wordpress (hence it mentions that to modify something in the rest-api plugin)

is there a way to do a filter to show all users in wordpress like to write a filter function inside of the functions.php file inside of the theme or is there something else ?

Comment: The last block of code in the link you posted is an option for if you don't want to modify the plugin, have you tried that?

Comment: @JacobPeattie currently using https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-wptheme to make a wordpress theme using react so there isn't a functions.php inside of the custom theme that is provided in create-react-wptheme so any suggestions?

Comment: If it’s a theme in the themes directory then just create the functions file yourself. Or make a simple plugin or use the snippets plugin. There’s plenty of ways to add that code.

Comment: @JacobPeattie just tried the snippets plugin and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much! never thought of it actually